# how can I sort SelectListItem value in numerically ascending order

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I am trying to sort the selectlist item value in numerically ascending order. At the moment it is coming sorted order but the order is coming alpha numeric order. For example  the  value of the selected list item are '1','2','3','12','13' . I would like to show the drop down in the given order. But in dropdown, it is being showed '1','12','13','2' so on
How can make it numeric sorting order . My model is

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Category Name")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In controller

```
IEnumerable<Category> CatList =   _unitOfWork.Category.GetAll();
        ProductVM productVM = new ProductVM()
        {
            Product=new Product(),
            CategoryList = _unitOfWork.Category.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem {
                Text = i.CategoryName,
                Value = i.Id.ToString()
            }),
```

I want to  show the text i.CategoryName in the order of Id.

Thanks
Pol

Comment: Provided that `GetAll()` returns IEnumerable<T>, first sort and then create a list of SelectListItems. `_unitOfWork.Category.GetAll().Orderby(i => i.Id).Select(i => new SelectListItem {Text = i.CategoryName, Value = i.Id.ToString()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current ordering you're seeing is such because, `Id` in your case is of string type and the strings are sorted in ascending order. Rather, you can first sort the list using `OrderBy` extension method of `LINQ` and then create a list of type `SelectListItem`. The modified method would look like below

```
// ...other code
// OrderBy sorts elements in a sequence in Ascending order
ProductVM productVM = new ProductVM()
{
    Product=new Product(),
    CategoryList = _unitOfWork.Category.GetAll().OrderBy(i => i.Id)
        .Select(i => new SelectListItem {
                Text = i.CategoryName,
                Value = i.Id.ToString()
})
// ...other code
```

More from the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1)